# Examples of one-way pseudo-random permutation?

Tags: pseudo-random-permutation

One-way functions have many candidates such as integer factorization. I am interested in combinatorial one way permutations. Specifically, I am interested in known one-way pseudo-random permutations (ideally a survey paper).